# Density Estimator of Gaussian Mixture differs from Density Plot

Tags: python, scipy, probability-density, kernel-density, mixture

I have a dataset `x` which is generated as a sample of a mixture of four different Gaussians:

```
mus = [60,150,300,500]
sigmas = [5,10,10,50]
Ns = [380,670,440,810]
Ns_rel = [i/sum(Ns) for i in Ns]
x = []
for mu,sig,N in zip(mus,sigmas,Ns): 
    x = np.append(x,st.norm(mu,sig).rvs(N))
```

A kernel density plot via `seaborn.kdeplot(x)` of the dataset `x` yields:

[image]

The plot of the "real" density of the gaussian mixture yield -- however -- a totally different graph:

```
x_plot = np.arange(-200,1400)
y_plot = np.zeros(1600)
for mu,sig,N in zip(mus,sigmas,Ns_rel): 
    y_plot += st.norm(mu,sig).pdf(x_plot)*N
```

Plotting the kernel-density-estimation of the sample together with the real density yields two totally different graphs:

```
sns.kdeplot(x, label="Density Estimation of sample of Gaussian Mixture")
plt.plot(x_plot,y_plot, "-", label="Real density of Gaussian Mixture")
plt.legend()
```

[image]

The Density and the Density Estimation should to be very similar, specially when there are so many samples as in my example.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Looks like the seaborn density plot is heavily smoothed.  If I plot a histogram of your data using matplotlib (i.e. `plt.hist(x, bins=40, normed=True)`), and then plot the PDF over it, the histogram and the PDF are in agreement.

Comment: Try using a narrower bandwidth in the KDE plot, e.g. `sns.kdeplot(x, bw=0.15, ...)`.  Scroll down to the examples in the [`kdeplot` documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) to see an example of setting `bw=0.15`.

Comment: Oh yes! How could I have been that blind. Thank you very much!